# Extending from a button

Tags: c#, wpf, class, button

I'm trying to do a simple thing but without success.

I need to extend from a button and create a custom button with custom proprieties (nothing to do with styles or visual settings).

I have created a simple class in the namespace `AppEdil.UI`.

```
namespace AppEdil.UI
{
    class MainMenuButton : Button
    {
        public int MenuTabIndex { get; set; }

        public MainMenuButton() 
        {

        }
    }
```

}

Then in the window xaml i added the namespace:

```
xmlns:ui = "clr-namespace:EdilCaselle.UI"
```

And then i added the buttons:

```
 <!-- Clients -->
 <ui:MainMenuButton Style="{StaticResource mainMenuButtonStyle}" Width="70" Height="60" Margin="0, 0, 5, 0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">
     <ui:MainMenuButton.Content>
         <StackPanel>
             <Image Source="Images/Big_Icons/user.png" Height="32" Width="32"/>
             <TextBlock>Clienti</TextBlock>
         </StackPanel>
     </ui:MainMenuButton.Content>
 </ui:MainMenuButton>
```

But i get different errors:

- MainMenuButton does not exist in the AppEdil.UI namespace
- MainMenuButton class not found and that i must see if i missed a reference or an assembly
- MainMenuButton is not supported in a WPF
  application (Wtf?)

Can you help me?

Comment: Did you really mean this `xmlns:ui = "clr-namespace:EdilCaselle.UI"`? Also are the button and the window in the same assembly?

Comment: Your classes won't be available in XAML until you've built your project. Have you built it yet? Cleaning your project might be useful as well. Also, it might help (might not), but change your xmlns attribute to be `xmlns:ui = "clr-namespace:EdilCaselle.UI;assembly="`. You also may need to make your class public.

Comment: Thank you @Steve it was the 'public' keyword missing.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the public keyword from your class. Add that and it will work! :)